# MySQL Query for selecting most common substrings separated by whitespace in a column?

Tags: mysql, string, varchar

I have a MySQL database of recipes.  One of the columns, NAME, is a varchar(255).  Each NAME can be multiple words (e.g., "Chocolate Chip Cookies" and "Oatmeal Cookies").

I'm looking for a way to efficiently parse the recipe names into individual words, then return a list of the most common words.  So, given the two recipes above, the query would return:

cookies, 2
chocolate, 1
chip, 1
oatmeal, 1

Is there an efficient way to do this?  I could query all the results, split each recipe name into words, then build a data structure to do this outside the database.  Alternatively, I could split the strings up ahead of time and build a table.

I guess what I am really hoping for is to leverage the database to do this faster (like with an index).  I don't know if that's possible with a single query.

So, am I stuck building a table ahead of time?  Or can this be done efficiently with a single query?

Thanks!

Comment: Doing this outside the database will be the correct approach IMO, and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table uses the MyISAM storage engine and you build a `FULLTEXT` index over your `NAME` column, you could use [myisam_ftdump's `--count` option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/myisam-ftdump.html#option_myisam_ftdump_count) to obtain an overall count of each word.  Sadly, however, this would be outside of SQL.

Comment: Thanks.   myisam_ftdump recipes 2 -c | sort

Comment: Cookies are, by far, the most popular.